# Migrating to Azure DevOps Service. DataMigrationTool error - VS403310: An inconsistency was detected in some of the files in the collection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

I'm attempting to migrate our on-premises Azure DevOps Server to a cloud Azure DevOps Service.

I've run the DataMigrationTool but am getting the error:

*Validation completed 'Validate File Content Consistency' with result Failed, message VS403310: An inconsistency was detected in some of the files in the collection. This inconsistency needs to be corrected prior to running an import to Azure DevOps Services.*

There's nothing particularly useful in the logs, nor can I find much online and the Azure DevOps Services virtual support assistant doesn't have a clue.

Don't suppose anyone's encountered this before and could point me in the right directon?

Comment: What is your current on-prem Azure DevOps Server/TFS version? Including the update version. The tags just say 2020, not 2020 RTM/2020.1/etc.

Comment: It's Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2 (18.181.32404.7) but I couldn't find a pre-existing tag for this & I've not got priv to create my own yet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there was several [events](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) on 9/5 that would impact import process. The events have been fixed now. **So if you had this issue around the 9/5, please try again to check if the issue has disappeared.**

If not, **when encountering `VS403310` error, you need to contact Azure DevOps [customer support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) (not virtual support) to get more detailed information.** This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#vs403310).

Here are the detailed steps to create customer support ticket:

1. You need to have an active Azure subscription. Then, click [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) and select "Request Support" under "Basic".
2. Sign in with your account and you will be re-direct to Azure portal. Click "Create a support request".
3. Fill in the form in "Problem description" tab. You can fill in some blank with the information below:

   Issue type: Technical

   Service: Azure DevOps Services
   Summary: Migrating to Azure DevOps Service. DataMigrationTool error - VS403310: An inconsistency was detected in some of the files in the collection

   Problem type: Configuring Azure DevOps Services

   Problem subtype: Migrating from Azure DevOps Server or TFS
4. Click "Next" to "Additional details" tab. Briefly describe your problem and **provide import ID**. After that you need to fill in some basic questions like work time zone. Then click "Next" and "Review + Create" to create a support ticket.

Microsoft services will contact you through contact information you have left. The response time for tickets in severity C is 8 working hours, and for severity B is 4 working hours.

Comment: Thanks Jane, I have gone this route and had a really length set of DB queries to run, just not had time to run thru yet.